# Сравнивание строки через Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер

Требуется сравнивать текст из файла с вариантами из массива. В файле только начальная часть будет совпадать с одним из вариантов.
Пример: В файле будет в таком виде - e/u/1/5/1.0562/15:50, а одним из вариантов в массиве будет e/u/1/5/, эта первая часть будет одним вариантом из массива. Как это реализовать или куда копнуть или чем? Делаю на python3.

Comment: Если перевернуть задачу в другую сторону (не начало текста из файла сравнивать с элементами списка, а наоборот), то и решать станет проще.

Comment: @Эникейщик, как я понимаю тут разница не большая в каком порядке, по итогу все равно нужно выделять начало строки, хоть ее сравнивать, хоть с ней. я просто подобного ни разу не делал затрудняюсь с определением модуля чтобы было проще и быстрее.

Comment: Если элемент берется целиком (а я понял описание именно так), то есть разница.

Comment: @Эникейщик, к сожалению это мне не поможет с определением направления к реализации, это все равно если на вопрос как пройти в библиотеку слышишь: надо идти тем же путем что из библиотеки сюда. Мне хотя бы узнать как называется данная процедура.

Comment: Функция строки startswith().

Comment: @Эникейщик, спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Пишите функцию поиска самой длинной совпадающей части двух строк.
2. Сравниваете со всеми образцами и запоминаете длину совпавшей части.
3. Находите максимальную длину
4. Соответствующий образец - то, что Вы ищите.

Нечто вроде:

```
# Функция проверки начала строк
def len_equ(s1, s2):
    rc = 0
    while s1[rc] == s2[rc]:
         rc = rc + 1

    return rc

# Образцы для сравнения
key_preffix = (
    'z1234',
    '1zzzz',
    '12zzz',
    '123zz',
    '1234z',
    '123xx',
    '12xxx',
    '1xxxx'
)

# Проверяемая строка
test_string = '12345'

# Проверяем размер совпадающей части в начале строки
result = dict()
for s in key_preffix:
    w = len_equ(s, test_string)
    result[s] = w

# print(result)

# Ищем максимальное значение сопадения
max_equ = max(result.values())
# print(max_equ)

# Какому образцу соответствует найденное максимальное значение?
found = "Ничего не найдено"
for key in result.keys():
    if result[key] == max_equ:
        found = key
        break

print("Образец максимального соответсвия: '{0}'".format(found))
```